# Deleting row by tag

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tags

I am currently trying to create a sort of tasktracker.. The following code works currently, but I need it to delete the row with the tag of the button.. In other words.

When button with tag:0 is pressed, delete row with tag:0

All my atempts have failed so I'm bringing it to the experts.

```
 - (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSInteger *row = button.tag;
        NSString *cleanedUp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
            if(button.titleLabel.text == @"Unchecked"){
            [button setTitle:@"Checked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
            [button setTitle:@"Unchecked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:button.titleLabel.text 
                                                        message:cleanedUp
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

Comment: I do not understand what "row" you are trying to delete. Also remove the `*` on `NSInteger *row` I am sure that is causing some warnings for you.

Comment: I have multiple cells with a ui button in each. The uibutton's tag is set to the cell's indexpath.row. When this function is called I wan't to animate out that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` has [built-in capabilities to allow the deletion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1) of rows. This may be better suited for what it sounds like you are trying to accomplish. Here is an [example](http://iphoneproghelp.blogspot.com/2008/12/uitableview-part-ii.html).

To use custom buttons you will need use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` to modify your table view animated.

```
NSInteger row = button.tag;
[tableView beginUpdates];
//make sure you remove the row from your datasource 
//as well or an exception will be raised
[self.datasource removeObjectAtIndex:row]
[deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]
       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I am aware. But i'm trying to make a custom checkbox using UIButton and images. When the "checkbox" is checked I want the row to fadeout (to appear in the "completed" section)